# using a lookahead to get the last occurrence of a pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was able to build a regex to extract a part of a pattern:

```
var regex = /\w+\[(\w+)_attributes\]\[\d+\]\[own_property\]/g;
var match = regex.exec( "client_profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][own_property]"  );
match[1] // "foreclosure_defenses"
```

However, I also have a situation where there will be a repetitive pattern like so:

"client_profile[lead_profile_attributes][foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][own_property]"

In that case, I want to ignore [lead_profile_attributes] and just extract the portion of the last occurence as I did in the first example. In other words, I still want to match "foreclosure_defenses" in this case.

Since all patterns will be like [(\w+)_attributes], I tried to do a lookahead, but it is not working:

```
var regex = /\w+\[(\w+)_attributes\](?!\[(\w+)_attributes\])\[\d+\]\[own_property\]/g;
var match = regex.exec("client_profile[lead_profile_attributes][foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][own_property]");
match // null
```

match returns null meaning that my regex isn't working as expected. I added the following:

```
\[(\w+)_attributes\](?!\[(\w+)_attributes\])
```

Because I want to match only the last occurrence of the following pattern:

```
[lead_profile_attributes][foreclosure_defenses_attributes]
```

I just want to grab the foreclosure_defenses, not the lead_profile.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working without positive lookahead:

```
regex = /(\[(\w+)_attributes\])+/
/(\[(\w+)_attributes\])+/
match = regex.exec(str);
["[a_attributes][b_attributes][c_attributes]", "[c_attributes]", "c"]
```

Comment: It seems that by default it returns the last occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to also achieve it through noncapturing groups. Output from chrome console:

```
var regex = /(?:\w+(\[\w+\]\[\d+\])+)(\[\w+\])/;
undefined
regex
/(?:\w+(\[\w+\]\[\d+\])+)(\[\w+\])/
str = "profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][properties_attributes][0][other_stuff]";
"profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][properties_attributes][0][other_stuff]"
match = regex.exec(str);
["profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][properties_attributes][0][other_stuff]", "[properties_attributes][0]", "[other_stuff]"]
```